# Is there an elegant way using loc to reduce a dataframe with arbitrary 'OR' statements?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

Let's say have a giant dataframe documenting the number of animals in a zoo

[Animal] ... [number]

[cow]    ... [3]

[fish]   ... [6]

.

.

.

[pig]    ... [5]

and I want to reduce this to look at n specific animals

then I would do something like this

```
df = df.loc[["Animal"]=="cow" | ["Animal"]=="pig" | ...]
```

for as many animals as I want

but how can I do this so for any given set

```
set = ["cow", "pig", .... ]
```

something of the form

```
df = df.loc[["Animal"] == i for i in set]
```

but this would make the union (i.e. it would look for places where Animal = cow AND pig AND all everything else)

Is there a version where It will look for the intersection ( i.e. Animal = cow OR pig OR anything else)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas, are you trying to search for rows where 'Animal' is in some sort of list? If so then this is a dupe

Comment: basically `df = df.loc[df['Animal'].isin(set)]` by the way don't use variable names that are python reserved words, using `set` shadows the type `set`

Comment: Great, Thank you